# What's the difference between PointCloudConstPtr and PointCloud::ConstPtr

Tags: ros-kinetic, roscpp

[image: Rosanswers logo]

In subscriber callbacks our software stack uses a mixture of two function signatures.  In the case of subscribing to a sensor_msgs::PointCloud, we use the following two signatures:

1. `void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloud::ConstPtr& msg)`
2. `void callback(const sensor_msgs::PointCloudConstPtr& msg)`

These are both defined in the autogenerated header `PointCloud.h`

```
template <class ContainerAllocator>
struct PointCloud_
{
  // ---- Snip ----
  typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::sensor_msgs::PointCloud_<ContainerAllocator> const> ConstPtr;
};
typedef ::sensor_msgs::PointCloud_<std::allocator<void> > PointCloud;

typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::sensor_msgs::PointCloud > PointCloudPtr;
typedef boost::shared_ptr< ::sensor_msgs::PointCloud const> PointCloudConstPtr;
```

Expanding the typedefs myself, I get the following

1. **`sensor_msgs::PointCloud::ConstPtr`**

`boost::shared_ptr< ::sensor_msgs::PointCloud_<ContainerAllocator> const>`

2. **`sensor_msgs::PointCloudConstPtr`**
   `boost::shared_ptr< ::sensor_msgs::PointCloud_<std::allocator<void> > const>`

It's not clear to me what ContainerAllocator gets set to in case 1, and I'm also not sure what the purpose of ContainerAllocater is.  Why would I choose one incantation over the other?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/293494/what%27s-the-difference-between-pointcloudconstptr-and-pointcloud::constptr/) by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on ROS Answers with karma: 760 on 2018-06-07

Post score: 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

These are the same.

`PointCloud_::ConstPtr` is templated on the `ContainerAllocator`, but the `PointCloud` typedef specifies a default container allocator of `std::allocator<void>`, so they're the same.

I'm not sure why there are two aliases for the same symbol.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2018-06-07

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [vpradeep](https://answers.ros.org/users/101/vpradeep/) on 2018-06-07**:
Makes sense.  You're right that `PointCloud::ConstPtr` uses `std::allocator<void>`, and hence they're the same.  I guess I just tripped myself up when attempting to expand the typedefs by hand.  Thanks for the clarification.